# Developing .Net Application on Mac?

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I am .Net Developer who started using Mac OS. The only thing that I miss on this system is "VISUAL STUDIO".
I don't wanna use two systems, What do you think in order to develop .Net application

Do you think that I should install Virtual box and use Visual Studio
http://zeus.cs.pacificu.edu/chadd/InstallVisualStudioOnYourMac.html

Or Just use Mono Develop? Is Mono Powerful enough to develop application that is compatible with Windows and run on Mac ?

Comment: Please try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ for this question. (Stack Overflow is primarily for specific programming problems).

Comment: Unless you want to develop GUI applications (hope you won't), MonoDevelop is powerful enough.

Comment: I use Visual Studio in a Parallels VM on my Mac very successfully.  However, this is very different from the last part of your question... "develop application that is compatible with Windows and run on Mac."  What exactly do you mean by that?  You might be misunderstanding something about the differences between the two.

Comment: @David : Thanks David, I am checking. There is no prob ! Do you recommend that. Is it heavy for Mac OS and for the productivity

Comment: @DataT: Running a VM is a matter of hardware more than software.  It's not "too heavy for Mac OS" but might be a bit much for an older machine.  My 2-year-old MacBook Pro handles Mavericks with a Windows 8 VM using Parallels just fine, though.  Note that it's still just developing Windows applications.  They don't "run on a Mac" they just run in Windows inside of a VM which happens to be on a Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am purely .NET developer, but lately also developing iOS applications with using Xamarin (new name for mono libraries) and Xamarin studio (rebranded Monodevelop).

So, if I understand you correctly and you still want to develop .NET applications but just working and "live" in MacOS, the I would say that you have **no chances**.

Even if consider, that you can have an ability to write code (and even to have some .NET libraries to use even there) in Monodevelop, that's just **incomparable**, how VisualStudio is amazingly convenient for developer (especially, for native .NET one) and how many plugins it has.

So, from my point of view, there is even no talk: you must use VisualStudio in any case! Even if you use it in Remote Desktop.

**UPD:** Time flows and things change. Currently .NET is really spread even to Mac. Visual Studio Code been released for coding and Xamarin became available for Free since the answer was asked.
However, one thing will probably never come true: I am doubting Visual Studio will ever be able to migrate from Windows. It will be rather some new product or extending of Visual Studio Code.

Comment: i think you should update your answer :)

Comment: @VikasRana, why? Has MS delivered VisualStudio for Mac already?!

Comment: we can use visual studio on mac and linux as by Official Asp.Net forum https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/code-vs.aspx

Comment: Please, read carefully what actually VisualStudio Code is (and what it can do), as that's absolutely another product, which just looks similar. Those are completely different ones, targeting (partially) different areas as well. First one is multi-platform though.

Comment: thnks for info @Agat :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use Mono to develop an application that is compatible with Windows, although Mono is nowhere near as robust/easy to use/ feature filled as VS.

That said depending on the type of application you plan to develop, it may make sense to install windows in a virtual box so that your application can actually *run* on your computer.

For example, if you are trying to make a Windows Forms application, your app ( which can be completely developed in Mono, but will not run on the native OS X. This will most likely make debugging a nightmare.

If you're on the fence  it might make sense for you to download a [90 day free trial](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh699156.aspx) of a windows OS from microsoft, run that in a virtual box and try out visual studio.

Comment: Mono is pretty stable and has many advanced features not available in Microsoft .NET.

Comment: I'm not trying to bash Mono unnecessarily- it is an **EXCELLENT** open source tool with plenty of features for advanced users. I just want to make it easy for the user to explore all possible options. [Here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/download-windows-xp-for-free-and-legally-straight-from-microsoft-si/) is a decent tutorial on running microsot xp in a virtual box.