# Mono error when running C# application on Mac: Invalid IL code in System.Drawing.Icon

Tags: c#, .net, macos, mono, system.drawing

Note: This is not a duplicate of the linked question because I'm not looking to develop a Mac application.

So I have a C# application on .NET 4.5 that has the following:

> 1) Windows Forms
>
> 2) References to System.Drawing, EmguCV, Aforge.NET dlls

This works perfectly on my Windows system.

When I try to run the program on a Mac system running OSX using Mono, I get the following error:

> exception inside UnhandledException handler: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.Form
>
> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.Form ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Drawing.Icon:.ctor (System.IO.Stream): method body is empty.
>
> at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Icon:.ctor (System.IO.Stream)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.ResourceImageLoader.GetIcon (System.String name) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Form..cctor () [0x00000] in :0

Has anyone faced anything like this? Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Developing .Net Application on Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934378/developing-net-application-on-mac)

Comment: Not really, I do not want to develop an application on Mac.

Comment: 1) What version of Mono are you running? 2) Are you using/copying a reference assembly vs. a BCL/PCL assembly as the "Invalid IL code in System.Drawing.Icon:.ctor (System.IO.Stream): method body is empty" would indicate that is what is happening

Comment: Hey @RobertN, 1) I'm using the latest stable mono release 4.2 for Mac and 2) I have a bunch of references that I am copying yeah, but I'm not sure what a BCL/PCL assembly is? Can you explain please?

Comment: When you ran it on windows did you use dot net or mono? I'm guessing you used dot net, and that there's a windows forms dll for mono that you should use instead of the dot net windows forms dll.

Comment: Yes I used .net when running on Windows. Can you point me towards the Mono Windows forms dll? Also I feel the error might be in the System.Drawing dll because of the inner exception, why do you think the error is with the windows forms dll?

Comment: Mono's WinForms is not perfect. To workaround you might disable the icons.